# Extracting Video Frames with Correct Resolution/Aspect Ratio

Tags: ffmpeg, resolution, vlc-media-player, aspect-ratio

I am using FFMPEG to extract I frames from Videos and ran into a problem.

The video resolution changes between 720x576 and 1024x576 and I can see this when playing the video in VLC and the VLC screenshots have the correct resolution.

In contrast, Apple QuickTime displays the whole video in the 1024x576 resolution.

When I export frames with FFMPEG, they all have the same resolution, even if the resolution at a specified timecode is different.

I am using the following commands.

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter:v "select='lt(prev_pts*TB\,2600)*gte(pts*TB\,2600) i%03d.png

ffmpeg -i input -vf "select=eq'(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)'" -vsync vfr if%04d.png -fflags discardcorrupt
```

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is most likely related to the Aspect Ratio. Look for SAR and DAR video properties. You may also check the aspect ratio using a [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool. As the question is detailed, it is hard to know the exact problem. What is the resolution of the PNG images? What is the resolution when playing with FFprobe? What do you mean "The video resolution changes between 720x576 and 1024x576"? Does the resolution change during the play (video suddenly gets larger)?

Comment: The images extracted with ffmpeg are always 720x576. According to MediaInfo and ffprobe the resolution of the video is 720x576, but yes, the video size changes when the video switches from 4:3 to 16:9, it gets larger. MediaInfo shows a 4:3 aspect ratio.

Comment: As I understand it, the input is a mixture of 4:3 and 16:9 aspects (720x576 ratio is 5:4)... The aspect ratio parameters are (allowed to be) attached to every key frame and possibly to every frame. Some video players reads the ratio once, and ignore the rest (VLC isn't). PNG image format supports aspect ratio metadata, but I don't think FFmpeg passes the ratio setting from the video. The resolution is going to be 720x576 regardless. I think you may try using `scale` filter as follows: `ffmpeg -i input -vf scale=w=in_w*sar:h=in_h i%03d.png` (but I think FFmpeg uses the first `sar`).

Comment: FFmpeg seams to stay with the first SAR. I cut a part of the 16:9 scene from the video and MediaInfo tells me the same resolution for this clip (720x576), but shows an aspect ratio 16:9 instead of 4:3. Is there a way to get the aspect ratio for each frame from FFmpeg? Or filter frames by aspect ratio?

Comment: Does the command `ffmpeg -i input -vf scale=w=in_w*sar:h=in_h i%03d.png` solves your issue (when applied to the 16:9 part)?

Comment: It does not find any matches.

Comment: What do you mean "does not find any matches"? What matches are you talking about? I am asking if the `scale` filter: `scale=w=in_w*sar:h=in_h` creates the PNGs with your desired resolution? (or do you want something else - not chaining the resolution?). I am going to pass... Next time you ask a question make sure to be very clear describing the issues and the objectives.

Comment: Sorry, I have calculated the width wrong, I was citing the output, "no matches found". Now I get all frames (tested with both videos), the 16:9 frames have the correct aspect ratio, rendered in a letterbox.